# Is it possible to bind variables in select clause?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

Can we bind variables in select clause like this:

```
String sql = "select ? name from user";
PreparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pstmnt.setString(1, "name");
```

or can we bind variables in where clause only?

Comment: This depends on the DBMS you're using. For some it works, for some you need to cast the parameter to a specific type, and for others it is not possible. Please tag your target DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind variables wherever you want. But you cannot bind identifier names e.g. database, table and column names (which is what you seem to be trying to do). The result of your sample code will look something like this:

```
name
----
name
name
name
```

I.e. it will select the constant string literal `'name'` for each row in the table.

Comment: Binding parameters in the select clause is not supported by all database systems, or for some it requires an explicit cast.

Comment: Which ones for example? I'll add to my answer.

Comment: DB2, HSQLDB and Firebird require you to cast, older versions of Firebird didn't support it all. I believe Derby and H2 also have (or had) issues with this.